# Read UTF-8 content from the XML file in Tridion multimedia component - Templating C#

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to read an XML file content embedded in Multimedia Component through templating(C#). The XML file contains few UTF-8 characters. When I read the xml content, the the output is translating the UTF-8 characters into some garbage characters(? symbols or rectangle boxes).
Below is the code snippet that I used in C# Templating.

Code 1:

```
Component xmlMultimediaComponent = (Component)XMLMMSRepositoryObject;
// read xml in multimedia component into a string
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] binary = xmlMultimediaComponent.BinaryContent.GetByteArray();
string navXmlContent = (binary != null) 
               ? UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binary, 0, binary.Length) 
                       : string.Empty;
```

Code 2:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  xmlMultimediaComponent.BinaryContent.WriteToStream(ms);
  ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
  {                      
    string output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
      ....
  }
}
```

In both of the above cases, the output is having garbage characters(for UTF-8 encoded).

Any idea how to get the same UTF-8 content into the string output from the XML file in Tridion multimedia component.

Note: The XML File in the multimedia component is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps paste your sample UTF8 content here so we can test with it

Comment: On a side note - having MMCs that don't contain binaries (e.g. text, xml, etc) is considered bad practice by many. If you need to store XML in Tridion, then you could use Components having a non-RTF multi-value text field.

Comment: Chris - Below is the sample content snippet from the XML file present in Multimedia component.                                           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
  <structuredgroup name="XYZ" id="tcm:67-345-4" parentorgitemid="tcm:67-344-4" xmlns="" description="&#xA;        &lt;strong xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt;XYZ&lt;sup class=&quot;sup&quot;&gt;®&lt;/sup&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&#xA;     &lt;br xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot; /&gt;&#xA;(sample description of XYZ)" />  
</root>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further investigation, we noticed that the file associated in Multimedia component is ASCII encoded. So there must not be explicit conversion to UTF-8 while reading its contents, and it should go with default encoding(i.e, ASCII in above case).

```
       Component xmlMultimediaComponent = XMLMMSRepositoryObject as Component;               
       byte[] binary = xmlMultimediaComponent.BinaryContent.GetByteArray();
       string navContent = (binary != null) ? Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII") : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Yeah instead of encoding explicitly; In above case you need to  keep output package to be utf-8 at target type setting level.

Answer (score 2):

May I ask why are you trying to load a Xml document into a string?

Try loading your XML Document into an object that understands XML Documents (like `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`), since they will know what to do with Byte Order Marks.

Something along the lines of `XDocument.Load(stream)` (.NET 4).

Then you can use that object's "OuterXml" string property if you *really* need the text of that document.

**EDIT**

Reading through your code, it looks like you're basically trying to output XML stored as a binary (or xml that does not comply to a Tridion schema), which is not what I would call a best practice. Anyway, you can set the output of the template as a XmlDocument, doesn't need to be a string. Look at the package.CreateItem variations.